# Density of states change in basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I have my density of states (continuous energy) in some basis $|l\rangle$ given by

$g_l(\epsilon) = \sum_l \delta(E_l-\epsilon)$

And I want to express it in terms of $|j\rangle$ where I have the following:

$|j\rangle = \sum_l \alpha_l^j|l\rangle$, where the $\alpha$'s are known.

The issue is that neither $|j\rangle$ nor $|l\rangle$ are energy eigenstates. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: If $l$ is not an energy eigenstate, then what exactly is $E_l$? The expectation of energy in $l$?

Comment: Yes. $l$ labels a certain observable (orbital angular momentum) and $E_l = \sum_n E_n|n\rangle\langle n|l\rangle$ where $|n\rangle$ are the energy eigenstates.

Comment: @user3518839 What eigenstates $|n\rangle$ are you considering in the summation in the definition of $E_l$. Or is $E_l=\int_n E_n |n\rangle \langle n|l \rangle$? If so, $E_l$ is the action of the Hamiltonian on the eigenstate $|l \rangle$ of an observable?

Comment: @Razor Yeah $E_l$ is the expectation value of the Hamiltonian on the state $|l\rangle$

Comment: If $E_l$ is a scalar $\langle l|H|l\rangle$, the function $g$ seems to be basis independent. What am I missing here?

Comment: @user3518839 first of all, $g$ shouldn't have dependency on $l$ in your first equation because $l$ is already summed up. Second of all, your definition of $E_l = \sum_n E_n | n \rangle \langle n | \rangle $ is wrong because the lhs is just a number where as the rhs is a state (i.e. a linear combination of $ | n \rangle$). Perhaps, you need to make sure your equations right first.